# Copy formula down a column until the last row without using dim

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel VBA macro that does a lot of vlookups and I need to copy the formula down the column. If I record the macro then it will only copy down to the same amount of rows. I run this file every week and the number of rows will always be different. I edit the VBA code to copy down the column but it only works once, then the other columns will get an error. Here is part of my code:

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-23],'[GEM Crossover.xlsx]GEM_Crossover'!C1:C2,2,FALSE))),VLOOKUP(RC[-23],'[GEM Crossover.xlsx]GEM_Crossover'!C1:C2,2,FALSE),IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(RC[-16],LEFT(RC[-14],1)),'[PRIVATE SWITCH.xlsx]Sheet1'!C1:C3,2,FALSE))),VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(RC[-16],LEFT(RC[-14],1)),'[PRIVATE SWITCH.xlsx]Sheet1'!C1:C2,2,FALSE),IF(AND(LEFT(RC[-14],1)=""P"",RC[-12]=""I""),RC[-16],IF(AND(LEFT(RC[-14],1)=""P"",RC[-12]=""X""),RC[-16],RC[-14]))))"
Range("X2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("X2:X" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
Columns("X:X").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

The code above works perfectly fine, but how come it doesn't not work when I use this code for another column?:

```
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]&RC[2]"
Range("B2").Select
Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

I set the autofill destination to the same as the first code. I just changed the columns from X to B and it won't work. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following line:

```
Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
```

You're getting the last row of column B (`2`):

```
Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
```

But this is the same column you're attempting to autofill, so it's presumably empty (below `B2`, anyway). Try using a different column to determine the last row. `A`, perhaps?

```
Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
```

Comment: Ok thanks changing the 2 to "A" fixed it. I just don't get how it worked for the formula above. ("X2:X" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2) I used that and it seem to fill all the way down.

Comment: When you use it for column X, does column B have data filled already?

Comment: o yes it does, that is probably why. Since the next line I add a column into column B. Thanks a lot